# Error restarting httpd during OTRS Install on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, apache, installation, otrs

I'm trying to install OTRS Help Desk 3.3.2 on Cent OS 6.5 (Final). The initial installation (`yum install`) goes smoothly enough. The next step is to restart `httpd`, but the restart keeps failing. I don't get an error in the console, but when I check the error logs, I can see that it fails each time for the same reason:

```
[Mon Dec 09 15:59:42 2013] [error] Can't locate 
    /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl in @INC 
    (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 
    /usr/local/share/perl5 
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl 
    /usr/lib64/perl5 
    /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at (eval 2) line 1

[Mon Dec 09 15:59:42 2013] [error] Can't load Perl file: 
    /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl 
    for server vsvrotrsdev.companydomain.com:0, exiting...
```

I'm a Linux/Apache/OTRS noob, so I'm not sure what to do with the error. Searching hasn't yielded much so far.

**EDIT**

I found some posts on what `@INC` is and how it works. I've tried adding /opt/otrs/scripts to @INC, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not positive this is your issue, as it could be several things. In newer versions the installation has been made easier, but I found part of the configuration for apache to be a little off. If you look in your OTRS conf file (on CentOS it is /etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_otrs.conf) on about line 14 you will see:

`<IfModule mod_perl.c>`

if your mod_perl is included as mod_perl.so this causes an issue, simply change it to

`<IfModule mod_perl.so>`

Comment: Whata f...!! All other apache modules uses *.c extension, but if I changed to .so it's works.